# Disable "hold press" to zoom on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, mobile

I'm experiencing some issues due to behaviour of some phone browsers (I'm on iOS) where when you hold finger in one place for a while it zooms in showing magnifying glass. Is it possible to get rid of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of this is to allow users to select text on a page. You can add `-webkit-user-select: none` to the css of whatever element you want the magnifying glass to not appear on, but this will also remove the ability to select text.